# Cufon with hover on parent element

Tags: css, hover, space, cufon

This is what I have: http://thezoomer.net/clubroyale/

I applied Cufon on the **a** element inside the .nav-item

```
Cufon.replace('.nav-item a', {fontFamily: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz',
                                    hover:true,
                                    hoverables: { li:true }
                                    });
```

This is what I have inside the menu

```
<li class="nav-item"><a href="./">HOME</a></li>
```

and this is what I have inside the css

```
.nav-item{
     color: #a8956c;
     background-color:#fff;
     cursor:pointer;

    white-space:nowrap;
}   
.nav-item:hover{
     color: #fff;
     background-color:#a8956c;

}
```

Evidently, I want the css hover to work. I know It will not work in this state because Cufon has tied the refresh to the a element and not the whole parent element (which is tied from the css ). However, if I apply the css to **.nav-item a** the hover will work but only on the portion of the menu element.

Also, I have tried applying Cufon on **.nav-item** without the **a**, the hover works but some Cufon draws some weird white spaces without having to.

So, is there something like hoverables: { parent:true } for the element to receive hover events from the parent element too ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work as expected:

JS:

```
Cufon.replace('.nav-item a', { fontFamily: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', hover: true });
```

CSS:

```
.nav-item a {
    color: #a8956c;
}

.nav-item a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: sure, but the problem is I want the background to also change, that is on .nav-item.. ok, if there is no way to bind Cufon to listen to parent hovers, I'll add the background on the a element, thanks!

Comment: This CSS is meant as an addition to your styles. Not a replacement. Keep the declaration for the BG to change on hover as it was and it *should* work.

Comment: In general, styling & hover effects should be applied to the element that has the click behavior bound to it. In your case, the <A> element. Having hover effects on the parent <li>, but only being able to click on the <a>, is a minor annoyance for the UX.

Of course, there are always exceptions.